# Прогнозирование последующих возможных значений целых чисел для заданной последовательности

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, sklearn

Есть пример кода из интернет, которые для заданной последовательности целых чисел прогнозирует последующие целочисленные значение. 
Нужно изменить код так, чтобы он выдавал по три наиболее вероятных целочисленых значений для каждого прогнозируемого элемента. Как это сделать ?

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", module="sklearn", message="^internal gelsd")


#inputData = pd.read_csv(example.csv, delimiter=',', header=None)
#y = inputData.iloc[:,0]  #select first column, next column would be [:,1] etc.


listIntegers = [0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72]
y = pd.DataFrame(listIntegers)

def linearizer(lowerLimit, upperLimit): # including lower and upper limit!
    upperLimit += 1
    out = []
    while (lowerLimit < upperLimit):
        out.append(lowerLimit)
        lowerLimit += 1
    return out 

length_y = len(y.index) #Get the length of our output
x = []
x = linearizer(0, (length_y - 1)) #minus 1 to compensate for position 0

x = pd.DataFrame(x)

model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(x, y)

#build new array, 10 positions (as an example) ahead
positionsToPredict = 10 #want to predict future n items
new_data = linearizer(length_y, (positionsToPredict + length_y))
new_data = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

# feed the array into model.predict()
prediction = model.predict(new_data)

print('\nPredictions based on Linear Regression:\n\n',prediction)
```

Текущий результат

```
 [[ 84.]
 [ 96.]
 [108.]
 [120.]
 [132.]
 [144.]
 [156.]
 [168.]
 [180.]
 [192.]
 [204.]]
```

Ожидаемый результат (для примера)

```
7 элемент, значение 84, вероятность 99%
7 элемент, значение 83, вероятность 81%
7 элемент, значение 85, вероятность 67%
```

Comment: А как вы определили, что вероятность значения 84 равно 99%??? Регрессионная модель не имеет отношения к оценки неопределенности ее результата. Регрессионная модель дает точечную оценку. При желании можно посчитать ее доверительный интервал. Все.

Comment: А как подсчитать доверительный результат?  Моя основная задача  для ряда N целых чисел определить наиболее вероятных кандидатов (минимум 3) для N+1 числа.

Comment: Во первых, ни "доверительный результат", а "доверительный интервал".  Во-вторых, причем регрессия (с которой вы начали)  к вашей задаче  -  абсолютно непонятно. В третьих, если у вас одна модель, которая предсказала значение Х, то три наиболее вероятные значения - это Х-1,Х,Х+1. Если у вас разные модели, или они обучены на разных данных -  ну тогда да, они могут дать некоторые "разбросанные" ответы. Но и то, без всяких вероятностей.

Comment: Я пока не разбираюсь в инструментах и теме которую решаю. Использовал то, что мне казалось понятным и возможным как-то улучшить за счет модификации кода.  Надеюсь, кто-то предложит вариант решения задачки

Comment: Так описания задачи-то нет. Описание задачи начинается не с того, что "я выбрал метод, но меня не устраивает как он работает, мне надо его улучшить путем модификации кода ", а с того, что описывается проблема, которую надо решить, а уж метод и и его модификации вам может-быть подскажут. А вариант "исправления" вашего решения  -  правда очень некрасивый - я вам подсказал: X-1,Х, Х+1. Или строить три разные модели на разных тренировочных данных.